# Is a RAM upgrade required for this new dual boot configuration?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, multi-boot, linux-mint

My computer usage is very basic, mostly reading and writing documents and searching the Internet; no games.  I do this on an old [Toshiba Satellite C650](https://support.dynabook.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200012200) laptop with 3 GB RAM, running the original Windows 7 Home Premium operating system.  The laptop configuration, as sold, was intended to be usable for typical basic computing needs, and it does perform satisfactorily.

I plan to add Linux Mint 19.1 as dual boot.  My usage on Mint will be similar, using equivalent Linux applications.

Will the new configuration require an upgrade of the laptop's RAM?

---

<sub>*Note: this is an improved reposting of a closed question on behalf of the OP (see comment, below).  It is self-answered, but other high-quality, fact-based answers are welcome.*</sub>

Comment: Note: This is essentially a reposting of an earlier question, [Is a RAM upgrade required?](https://superuser.com/q/1455001/364367), which was closed due to the unfortunate original wording.  That question never recovered from the perception created by the initial wording and the responses to it on that thread.  However, the underlying question is a legitimate, on-topic one that may be shared by others, and can be answered on a factual basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Dual booting

The first thing to understand is that with dual booting, one operating system has no effect on the other.  Whichever OS is running has access to all of the computer's resources, and the other OS is just data occupying space on a drive.  You don't need additional RAM due to two OSes being installed, you just need to look at whether the RAM is adequate for each OS alone.

#### Windows 7

The Toshiba Satellite C650 came with Windows 7 Home Premium.  The specs don't state whether it was the 32-bit or 64-bit version, but it appears to be 64-bit because the maximum RAM spec is 8 GB, and the 32-bit version was capped at 4 GB.  You could confirm it, though (Start Menu, right-click on *Computer*, select *Properties* from the dropdown menu).  Just as an aside, even if Windows 7 is the 32-bit version, the laptop's hardware is 64-bit, so you can run a 64-bit OS.

Microsoft's published system requirement (minimum for reasonable performance) is stated as 2 GB RAM for the 64-bit version.

I found an Online Tech Tips article from 2011, contemporaneous with Windows 7, [Windows 7 RAM Requirements – How Much Memory Do I Need?](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-7-ram-requirements-how-much-memory-do-i-need/), that took this a step farther.   It has some general guidelines based on type of usage.  Excerpting cases that might apply based on your usage description:

> - 2GB of RAM for the average computer user (one who browses the net, uses Microsoft Word, plays solitaire, etc).
> - 4GB of RAM for the multimedia computer user (one who watches DVDs, watches streaming video, uses Photoshop, and does some light multitasking).
> - 6GB of RAM for the multitasking computer user (one who often has several programs open at once. If you do video editing or audio editing).

For the usage you describe, your computer's 3 GB RAM looks reasonable relative to the recommendations above, and you are apparently satisfied with the performance.  Adding Linux in dual boot mode won't affect Windows' performance in any way; Windows will continue to perform exactly as it does now.  So there's no requirement to upgrade RAM for Windows.

#### Linux Mint

Mint is available with three different desktop environments.  As implemented in Mint, there is not a huge difference in RAM requirements between those different versions, and Mint specifies the same minimum RAM for all three.  For example, their recommendation for Cinnamon (the heaviest; see [requirements per the release announcement](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3669)):

> 1GB RAM (2GB recommended for a comfortable usage)

The 2 GB figure aligns with Microsoft's recommendation.  Microsoft doesn't mention a similar "two-level range", but the article cited above states:

> 1GB of RAM should be the low minimum for running Windows 7. 2GB of RAM is probably not needed to run Windows 7 64-bit, but it would make multitasking better, and speed things up a bit.

That suggests that the needs are more or less comparable.  Neither Microsoft nor Mint offers fine-tuned advice based on different types of usage.  However, when Windows 7 came out, typical computer usage was far less demanding than it is today.  Microsoft assessed 2 GB as a reasonable minimum for typical usage then, and Mint assesses 2 GB as reasonable for typical usage today.  Mint also has the advantage over Windows 7 of another decade of development in memory utilization.

If we just take the 2 GB numbers at face value, we could assume that Mint and Windows 7 have comparable requirements.  However, there are still differences, like the fact that you probably won't be running an antivirus program in the background with Mint, so Mint will stretch your 3 GB farther than Windows 7.  Mint will perform at least as well with 3 GB as Windows 7, and you are satisfied with Windows 7's performance.

#### Bottom line

The current RAM already exceeds the recommended minimums for both operating systems to get reasonable performance on basic tasks.  It's already been proven adequate for Windows 7 and should be at least as good for Mint.  There is no requirement to increase RAM for Mint if you will be continuing to use the computer in the same way.

#### Would there be any benefit to adding RAM?

That depends.

- If your current use rarely exceeds available memory (suggested by performance being satisfactory), that means you're barely maximizing RAM usage now.  In that case, RAM you add would sit idle most of the time and would provide little benefit.
- If your current use sometimes lags, that could indicate that it's spending time swapping memory content to your hard drive because it's short on RAM.  In that case, additional RAM would minimize the lags.
- If you would like to use the computer in more demanding ways than you can now, like keep more applications open at the same time, keep a lot more tabs open in your browser, or run an application that is a memory hog, more RAM would let you do it.